# Error with parsing JSON with NSJSONSerialization

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode, parsing, openweathermap

I use [openweathermap API](http://openweathermap.org/current) to print current weather. I need to parse [this](http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/city.list.json.gz) JSON (JSON with available cities). I tried to parse it with NSJSONSerializer, but the answer was :"error NSError * domain: @"NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 3840".

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"city.list" ofType:@"json"];
NSString *myJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSError *error;
NSData *objectData = [myJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

As i understand, error 3840 says about wrong JSON format, but i have downloaded JSON from official openweathermap page. What's wrong? How parse this JSON correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The file is no valid JSON, but a list of valid JSONs.

```
{"_id":707860,"name":"Hurzuf","country":"UA","coord":{"lon":34.283333,"lat":44.549999}}
{"_id":519188,"name":"Novinki","country":"RU","coord":{"lon":37.666668,"lat":55.683334}}
{"_id":1283378,"name":"Gorkhā","country":"NP","coord":{"lon":84.633331,"lat":28}}
…
```

Such a list in a valid JSON would look like this …:

```
[
  {"_id":707860,"name":"Hurzuf","country":"UA","coord":{"lon":34.283333,"lat":44.549999}},
  {"_id":519188,"name":"Novinki","country":"RU","coord":{"lon":37.666668,"lat":55.683334}},
  {"_id":1283378,"name":"Gorkhā","country":"NP","coord":{"lon":84.633331,"lat":28}},
  …
]
```

… or like this …

```
{
  {"707860": {"name":"Hurzuf","country":"UA","coord":{"lon":34.283333,"lat":44.549999}},
  {"519188": {"name":"Novinki","country":"RU","coord":{"lon":37.666668,"lat":55.683334}},
  {"1283378":{"name":"Gorkhā","country":"NP","coord":{"lon":84.633331,"lat":28}},
  …
```

However, what you can do is to iterate over the list and convert it item separately:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"city.list" ofType:@"json"];
NSString *myList = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

// Separate the lines
NSArray *myItems = [myList componentsSeperatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newLineCharacterSet];

NSError *error;
for( NSString *JSON in myItems ) 
{
  if( [JSON length]==0) 
  {
    // empty line
    continue;
  }
  NSData *objectData = [JSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSDictionary *object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
  if( object == nil )
  {
    NSLog( @"Error %@ reading\n%@", error, JSON);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! But... First and last string in JSON file don't parse. After NSJSONSerialization i get "nil"... I simply can't understand why!!!  :(

Comment: So have a look at the error. That's what it is for.

Comment: Error was the same: "error NSError * domain: @"NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 3840". Wrong JSON format... But strings are similar

Comment: Ah, the last line will likely produce an error, because it is empty. I think something like that is wrong with the first line. I changed the code to deal with it. However, print out the corrupted line and the error. I added that, too.

Answer (score 0):

Your json is not formatted correctly.

```
{"_id":707860,"name":"Hurzuf","country":"UA","coord":{"lon":34.283333,"lat":44.549999}}
{"_id":519188,"name":"Novinki","country":"RU","coord":{"lon":37.666668,"lat":55.683334}}
```

should be

```
[{"_id":707860,"name":"Hurzuf","country":"UA","coord":{"lon":34.283333,"lat":44.549999}},
{"_id":519188,"name":"Novinki","country":"RU","coord":{"lon":37.666668,"lat":55.683334}},    
...]
```

Note the encapsulating square brackets and commas at the end.

Or you could parse the text line-by-line (it seems it is ment to be parsed like that).